# html element's attribute in c# web browser by using threading

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, browser, webbrowser-control

i am making web browser in windows form by using c# where i can set values of loaded html's input fields  automatically by clicking on button. when i simply put code in click event of button its work fine`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value","admin");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value","12345");


        }`
```

but when i try to this via threading it gives me error

> Specified cast is not valid?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(setvalues));
            thread1.Start();


        }

void setvalues() 
        {

                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value","admin");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value","12345");

                Thread.Sleep(8000);

            }
        }
```

where i am doing mistake in code ? any error? am beginner i need help

Comment: Please tag this with what c# web framework you are using.

Comment: @mxmissile i am using c# visual basic 2010

Comment: Which web framework though?  asp.net? asp.net core? Where is `webBrowser1` coming from?

Comment: @mxmissile am using windows form c# i just drag and drop web browser from toolbox in visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access forms controls in a separate thread. Try this in `setvalues()`:

```
Invoke((Action)(() => {
     webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value","admin"); 
     webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value","12345");
}));
```

Comment: at Invoke(()=> giving me error Cannot convert lambda to the type System Delegate because its not a delegate type

Comment: its working now, can you tell me how to refresh the any webpage in webbrowser1 with code?

Comment: You probably want to ask a new Question for that. More exposure.

Comment: are you greedy of your positive scores than teaching beginners? ok fine

Comment: haha no, you would get more exposure, and you would get more rep, and thats just how StackOverlfow works... :-)

Comment: That's not true, anyone can learn! Your off to a great start if your already dealing with threading! :-)